# How to set GWT Flextable first row (i.e heading) declaratively using UiBinder?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, flextable

I want my table to have the following static column headings: "Name", "Surname", "DOB", 
but I want to declare them in *.ui.xml (rather than in code).

Right now, I'm doing it via code like this:

```
public PersonViewImpl extends Composite implements PersonView {
    /*Lots of code removed for clarity*/

    @UiField (provided = true) FlexTable personTable;

    public PersonViewImpl(){
        personTable.setText(0, 0, "Name");
        personTable.setText(0, 1, "Surname");
        personTable.setText(0, 2, "DOB")    
    }
}
```

I have this in my PersonView.ui.xml

```
<g:FlexTable ui:field="personTable" />
```

I've googled for hours, but still no go.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set FlexTable's cell elements in UI Binder, probably you should have your own custom widget which renders tr and td. For example, like explained here: [GWT table row as UiBinder](http://pawelstawicki.blogspot.com/2010/11/gwt-table-row-as-uibinder.html)

Answer (score 1):

when you declare `provider = true`, the ui binder not instance the object, you need to instance it in your java class
the right code is:

```
public PersonViewImpl(){
    // enter code here
    personTable = new FlexTable();
    personTable.setText(0, 0, "Name");
    personTable.setText(0, 1, "Surname");
    personTable.setText(0, 2, "DOB");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this) );` on first line of constructor.

try this:

```
public class PersonViewImpl extends Composite implements PersonView {
    /*Lots of code removed for clarity*/

    @UiField (provided = true) FlexTable personTable;

    public PersonViewImpl(){
        initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this) );
        // TODO your code
    }
}
```